# Cannot set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in ccmake or cmake-gui

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I want to use `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to set a directory (say `/usr/local2`) for `cmake` to search for headers and libraries. I tried to use the command line

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local2 /path/to/src
```

But `cmake` does not seem to take that hint (i.e. it still found the library in system path `/usr/local`). I also tried `ccmake` and `cmake-gui`, but neither provide me the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` entry to edit. When I search for "PREFIX", the only one shows up is `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. Am I not looking at the right place? Or did I miss something when installing `cmake`?

I am using `cmake` version 3.1.3 (and also tried 3.0.2), which is installed with MacPorts. And I did remember to check the "advanced" box for all options.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file is pretty simple

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (my_project CXX)
find_package (PNG REQUIRED)
include_directories (${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable (my_executable test.cc)
target_link_libraries (my_executable ${PNG_LIBRARIES})
```

and I also made sure the `/usr/local2/lib` contains the `libpng.dylib` for `cmake` to search for.

In the `CMakeCache.txt` file, I found

```
//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:UNINITIALIZED=/usr/local2
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you share your project CMakeLists.txt?

Also, do you see a CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH entry in your CMakeCache.txt file in your build directory? The cmake command you posted should have set an entry in the cache, which should show up when you toggle the advanced box.

Comment: @atsui Thanks for your response. Please see my edits about the `CMakeLists.txt` and `CMakeCache.txt` files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you make a `/usr/local2/lib` directory and place `libpng.dylib` there (instead of just `/usr/local2`), cmake should be able to pick it up. The [manual](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) suggests that it just uses `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` as the base.

Comment: Yes, that is where I put `libpng.dylib`. I had a type-o in the question and fixed it. Thanks for pointing out. But `cmake` still cannot find it with the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` hint. BTW, if I set `CMAKE_BUILD_PREFIX` to `/usr/local2`, it will find and link to the library there.

Comment: I'm don't think setting `CMAKE_BUILD_PREFIX` has an effect since it isn't a cmake special variable. At least I couldn't get it to work for me in a clean build. I think `cmake` might not do anything if you already have `/usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib` cached. Have you tried clearing the build directory and doing a clean build?

Comment: Actually I meant `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. Sorry for the confusion. I tried to start a build directory from scratch, but it does not seem to help.